# Socket.IO integration with Redux in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io, redux, react-redux

I want to integrate **socket.io** with **Redux** in react native.
I created a socket helper js file, where `BusRouteAction.js` file is imported.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'
import { setRouteAction } from '../../ReduxModel/Actions/BusRouteAction'

var socket;

export function socketListener () {

    socket = io('http://busapp.globusdemos.com:6022/', {jsonp: false});

    socket.on('connectionCheck', (response)=> {
        console.log('socket connection' + response.message);
    });

    socket.on('getRoutesResponse', (response) => {
        console.log('route json response : ' + response);
        // this.props.routes(response.data);
    });
}

export default connect(matchDispatchToProps);
```

Please check my above code and let me know where i am going wrong.
I want pass `getRouteResponse` data to components through props.
But i am getting this.props is undefined.

Or is there any other methods, to implement. Please let me know.

Comment: this.props is undefined because there is no react-native component in your code.

Comment: Yes, i find out that. But is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: I like to use redux-saga for stuff like this - for example, your socket.on('getRoutesResponse' ...) method could trigger an action that then does something with the new data that was sent from a socket.  Another way to go is to register listeners with socket.on in a component directly.

Comment: Okay, i will check redux-saga. for now i am using socket.on in component only. But i think, it will be better, if i could put all the socket events in one js file.